# Error in sda.Fill (dt);

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have created a login page in Visual Studio 10. I get this error showing up every time I run the program:

[image]

Here's my code for `css/Default.aspx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class css_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=login;Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) From Log_Table Where UserName ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'",con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't open the connection.

```
con.Open();
```